# Finite calculus: General derivative of an exponent

Tags: discrete-calculus

I am reading through [Finite Calculus: A Tutorial for Solving Nasty Sums](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf) by David Gleich and on page 9 he computes the general derivative of an exponent:

$$
\triangle(c^x) = c^{x+1} - c^x = (c-1)c^x
$$

This part is clear to me. However then the text goes on to say

> Because $c$ is a constant in this expression, we can then immediately compute the anti-derivative as well
>
> $$
> \sum (c^x)\delta x = \frac{c^x}{c-1} + C
> $$

How is this immediate computation done? Are the rules of infinite calculus being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the sum and the difference cancel each other, hence

$$c^x=\sum\triangle(c^x) \delta x= \sum (c-1)c^x\delta x=(c-1)\sum c^x\delta x,$$

which results in

$$\sum (c^x)\delta x = \frac{c^x}{c-1} + C.$$

We need to add the constant because functions differing in a constant have the same difference.

Comment: Ah I see, the $(c-1)$ can be "taken outside" the sum by way of the distributive law and then we are rearranging to reveal the anti-derivative of $\sum(c^x)\delta x$